# systemd-nspawn container with separate IP address (network namespace) not working

Tags: networking, systemd-nspawn

Looking at the documentation for `systemd-nspawn`, it must have been intended to have a very user-friendly way to launch containers in a different network namespace.  You use the `-n` option, and simply enable `systemd-networkd.service` on both ends.  The container gets its own IP address in one of the "private" ranges.  (DNS might require some [additional step](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/456#issuecomment-119077631)).

The result is I get an IP address in the range `169.254.*.*`.  The default route points at the `host0` interface without going through any gateway/router.  Attempts to reach internet servers e.g. `8.8.8.8` fail with "No route to host".  (No point working out DNS if this doesn't work).

If I run `tcpdump -i ve-fedora-25` on the host, I can see the DHCP requests, but they are not responded to.  systemd-networkd is definitely running on the host.  The host-side logs show "Gained carrier" on `ve-fedora-25`, and networkctl shows this as "routable" & "configured" all in green.

My system is Fedora 25.  I want an OS container I can connect to using TCP/IP, and at the same time be able to connect out to the world (e.g. to run the `dnf` package manager).  Just as `libvirt` VMs work so easily out-of-the-box.  What has gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is Fedora's [firewalld](https://superuser.com/questions/918863/systemd-networkd-does-not-receive-dhcp-requests).  It seems nspawn was never integrated with firewalld.  (nspawn isn't correctly integrated with Fedora's SELinux policy either).

As mentioned in the question, libvirt is working fine :).  We can use the same trick people discovered for running containers with [LXC on Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/LXC).

**Update: the workaround stopped working after I upgraded to Fedora 30.**

---

Run systemd-nspawn with the option `--network-bridge virbr0`.  Instead of relying on `systemd-networkd`, this leverages `libvirtd.service`.  The latter service is already started by default on Fedora.  In the guest, set up your preferred DHCP client as usual.

### DNS resolution when using systemd-networkd as DHCP client

Using `systemd-networkd` as a DHCP client might *accidentally* work on its own, if you may have a left-over `/etc/resolv.conf` from a previous container boot.  But you can't rely on this working in general.  It's really designed to be run together with `systemd-resolved.service`.

In turn, systemd-resolved is intended to be used with `nss-resolve`.  However this is not essential AIUI.

Comment: You gave me a valuable clue, I had the same problem on Debian and using firewalls set via `ufw`.  DHCP started working when I disabled the firewall.  Link local addresses work even with the firewall running but only for local networking, wider routing is a no-go.